# Create a spreadsheet that filters data and allows users to edit filtered data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a master datasheet with lots of information. I extract data from the master to a simple overview pertaining to only specific groups of people which takes this data and calculates other specifics. This simple overview changes depending on my input. I want to send this simple overview to the specific groups and am wondering if there is some way to let them edit the information in the simple overview and have it update in the master datasheet. I am familiar with VBA if it needs to be programmed or if a macro needs to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two data sheet among which one is master and other is the one you can share with the specific group. You can write a VBA script for the master data sheet to make a copy of the required information to a new data sheet which can be shared with editing privilege to the specific group. The data sheet that is shared with the specific group will have a VBA script which will update the edited information back to the master datasheet.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I am hoping for. Do you have any examples of the script? What kinds of commands would I need?